# not able to import json file in opensearch that was exported from elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-opensearch

I have this json file that used to work on elastic but is not able to import anything in open-serach.

https://datameetgeobk.s3.amazonaws.com/cftemplates/export_se.json

Goto Kibana — Management — Saved Objects — Import and provide the path.
It should import 5 searches / visualizations. But I get a message "no file was imported"

Comment: The file used to work as expected on earlier versions of both, elastic and opensearch.

Comment: Which version of Elastic was this exported from? Also do you see something related in the Kibana logs?

Comment: It was generated from unknown version back in Nov 2019. I guess it can not be used now. I will create the views again. I thought there may be some utility to upgrade the config files.

Comment: Exported files are not always compatible between two versions of Elasticsearch itself, so between ES and OS is very unlikely. Still interested in looking at relevant Kibana logs, if any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exported files are not always compatible between two versions of Elasticsearch itself, so between ES and OS is very unlikely.